# How to replace or repaint system tray clock

Tags: c#, c++, windows, clock, tray

I want to replace system tray clock,and display more info on it,such as weather icon.
I have found three demos, here is one of them: http://www.stoicjoker.com/tclock/Download.php.

BUT I only program in C#, and these demos are all in C++,.

Is there a way to do it in C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not standard situation or possibility, that's easily available in Windows API. Here's another one: http://wincalendartime.sourceforge.net/index.html. From comments I can say process of overwriting clock is quite complicated (dll injection into Explorer & live subclassing of clock).

Comment: Thanks for your help.So,the only way to work it out is using dllimport,as you say it's quite complicated.I'll try C# import C++ project,hope I can make it